# 14.04 LTS on old Pressario Desk top is blank but short cuts are there if you can remember where they are!

Tags: nvidia, .desktop

I have a Compaq Pressario that has been running Ubuntu for a few years. Now I have the problem that I can log in and it refreshes the background, flashes then sits there, no icons. The mouse is active and I can click it then the screen goes black. I have managed  to launch the game "magic sokoban" by accidentally clicking on the right place. The graphics were fine.
I have done `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and am getting no errors.
The VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C51 [GeForce 6150 LE] (rev a2)

Any ideas please. I need to get access the data files. The computer is too old to have USB boot and I do not have a recovery CD.

Comment: Can you open a terminal session by pressing `control-alt-t`?

Comment: Yes I can and the cursor is now a text entry cursor but the screen is black so you cannot see what has been typed.